# Se genera el error en Python "TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python-3.x

Cordial saludo, tengo el siguiente error (TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable), mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
N = int(input())
db = [N]
for i in range (N):
  c = input()
  db.append(c.split( ))  
db  
P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, P7 = 240, 300, 160, 180, 240, 275, 50
parametros = [P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, P7]
for i in range(db[0]):
    if (int(db[i+1][0]) >= parametros [0]) and \
        (int(db[i+1][0]) <= parametros [1]) and \
        (int(db[i+1][1]) >= parametros [2]) and \
        (int(db[i+1][1]) <= parametros [3]) and \
        (int(db[i+1][2]) >= parametros [4]) and \
        (int(db[i+1][2]) <= parametros [5]) and \
        (int(db[i+1][3]) <= parametros [6]):
        disponibilidad = True
if disponibilidad [True]:
print(db[i][4])
else:
    print("no disponible")
```

y el error se genera en la linea if disponibilidad [True]:

agradezco cualquier orientacion

Comment: Solo quita el `[True]`. Por lo que se aprecia en tu código `disponibilidad` es boleano, por tanto basta con `if disponibilidad:`

Comment: Por qué escribiste [True]? No tiene sentido. Cree que intentas aplicar rebanado a un boleano. Cuál es el propósito?